# How to load specifc plugin to ajax handler in WordPress?

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using WordPress with WooCommerce installed. I notice that calling the WordPress API or WooCommerce API returns a slow response time.

I created a custom request handle so that my ajax call will not load the entire WordPress to serve the endpoints. The custom request handle file will just only serve the content and handle permissions.

**myajaxhandler.php**

```
<?php
    // Force a short-init since we just need core WP, not the entire framework stack
    define( 'SHORTINIT', true );
    require_once('../../../wp-load.php');

    echo 'aaa';
    WC()->session->set_customer_session_cookie(true);
    exit();    
?>
```

**custom-js.js**

```
var custom_ajax_url = 'http://localhost/mywebsite' + '/wp-content/plugins/zb-ajax-handler/myajaxhandler.php';

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: custom_ajax_url,
    cache: false,
    data: {
        action: 'getwcnonce'
    },
    success: function(data) {},
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```

The call to myajaxhandler.php file is ***successful*** but I am receiving an error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function WC() in
>   C:\XamppDev\htdocs\mywebsite\wp-content\plugins\zb-ajax-handler\myajaxhandler.php
>   on line 12

I think this is because WooCommerce plugin files are not recorgnized.

Do you know how can I **include/load** the WooCommerce plugin to my ajax handler so that I can call to WooCommerce and its functions?

Any idea is appreciated. Thanks..

Comment: This might be helpful...
https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/using-ajax-with-wordpress/

Comment: Thanks for that. I think ajax handler has a faster call

Comment: Check this. https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_plugin_active

Comment: Can you please write a code sample how to include woocommerce?

Comment: This is something the WordPress can't perform your request that way. There is different approach you can follow for ajax request in WordPress.

Comment: You added the `global $woocomerce;` , so you should use it: `$woocommerce->session->set_customer_session_cookie(true);`

Comment: @Jamie_D I tried your advice but this is the error that I encountered Fatal error: Call to undefined function untrailingslashit() in C:\XamppDev\htdocs\mywebsite\wp-includes\option.php on line 133

Comment: Since Woo is integrated into the WP rest api and user for plug in purchase validation, you are in for a head ache. You are going to have to include the WC rest api valdation keys. http://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#rest-api-keys

Comment: @JeremiahStillings I can include the WC Rest API keys through headers of my jQuery ajax request. What I need is to load woocommerce plugin even if there is a SHORTINIT constant.. Do you have any insights how to do this?

Comment: @ConanCarroll Have you tried including your config file in `myajaxhandler.php` Like this may help `include "../../../../wp-config.php";`

Comment: @ZainulAbideen Yes I tried adding wp-config. This is the error that I encountered Fatal error: Call to a member function set_customer_session_cookie() on null in C:\XamppDev\htdocs\mywebsite\wp-content\plugins\zb-ajax-handler\myajaxhandler.php on line

Comment: if you set SHORT_INIT to false, does problem persist?

Comment: Delicious Brains is a pretty authorative source. They tackled this in 2017. https://deliciousbrains.com/wordpress-rest-api-vs-custom-request-handlers/

Comment: A possible rabbit hole might be this plug in https://github.com/iruzevic/wordpress-rest-transient I think it solves your issue, but I am not 100 percent sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an interesting question indeed. Yes you are right - loading your whole WordPress installation (including WooCommerce) on each ajax request **can be slow**. Especially if you are doing a lot of requests (you are not the first one to have this problem: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/26254/how-to-include-wp-load-php-from-any-location).

However just including **wp-load.php** may simple be not enough. You may stumble upon missing functions and dependencies during processing your request which is causing your fatal error.

One possibility I can think of to slightly speed up load times would be to ***disable the loading of not required plugins during your ajax request*** (as you proposed) - example on how to do it which you can change to your needs:

```
    $request_uri = parse_url( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH );

    $is_admin = strpos( $request_uri, '/wp-admin/' );

    // add filter in front pages only
    if( false === $is_admin && !DOING_AJAX ){
        add_filter( 'option_active_plugins', 'disable_plugins_for_request' );
    }

    function disable_plugins_for_request( $plugins ){
        global $request_uri;
        $is_contact_page = strpos( $request_uri, '/contact/' );

        $unnecessary_plugins = array();

        // conditions: deactivate plugins if not certain page u.ä.
        if( false === $is_contact_page ){
            $unnecessary_plugins[] = 'contact-form-7/wp-contact-form-7.php';
        }

        foreach ( $unnecessary_plugins as $plugin ) {
            $k = array_search( $plugin, $plugins );
            if( false !== $k ){
                unset( $plugins[$k] );
            }
        }
        return $plugins;
    }
```

More info within this tutorial: https://kinsta.com/blog/disable-wordpress-plugins/

However way easier: **Setup a proper caching mechanism for your API**

Just do requests as usual and follow the instructions from the WordPress codex: https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

But cache the results ***using a caching Plugin or even your own caching mechanism***. You could do this by checking if a cache file exists for your current request and only if not you even start loading WordPress.

Comment: Is your code above good for a custom page like /forrad? because I am executing http requests on /forrad page or Do i need to modify something from your code above?

Comment: @ConanCaroll The code sample is showing how to correctly disable plugins on a per request basis. You can put a simple conditional depending on the page for instance. 

However I still would recommend the caching solution.

Comment: I am encountering a Fatal error: Call to undefined function add_filter() to the line add_filter( 'option_active_plugins', 'disable_plugins_for_request' ) -- Sorry, I am just a beginner in WP. Do you know how to avoid the add_filter error?

Comment: add_filter is a WordPress core function. Can you ensure WordPress is already loaded when you call it?

Comment: I tried declaring require_once('../../wp-load.php'); on top of the file but wordpress couldn't find wp-load file even though it's just 2 backwards away from the root project. Again, Thank you for  your help

Comment: This should help: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/26254/how-to-include-wp-load-php-from-any-location

Comment: Thanks for the guide, add_filter now works and I was able to do an action hook